# How to transaction rollback in ssis?

Tags: ssis

I have data import to Production server. In my package cleanse raw tables before data load. If any case package failed . How to rollback raw tables data in SSIS ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

By using **Sequence Containers** (Sequence, For Loop, ForEach Loop) in SSIS, you can make use of a property called **TransactionOption**.  This allows you to specify the transactional behaviour of the tasks in your package, and the package itself to rollback if any tasks fail.

For example, if you stick your tasks in a Sequence Container and set `TransactionOption=Required`, and configure all Tasks within the Container to `TransactionOption=Supported`, they will all join the transaction started in the Sequence Container, and if any fail, the transaction will be rolled back.

You can read an explanation of the TransactionOption property [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137690.aspx) and/or follow the [walkthrough here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141144.aspx) to see how to implement this.

EDIT: Another good [walkthrough (with screenshots) here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1585/how-to-use-transactions-in-sql-server-integration-services-ssis/)

Comment: Totally depends on the size of your transaction and how it's logged.  If you're running a massive transaction that takes hours and it fails, you could still be looking at a long time rolling back.

Comment: It's very help full for me Thank You so much.

Comment: WARNING !!! using transactions can cause problems. See my problem at - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19869276/cannot-connect-to-database-after-putting-tasks-in-sequence-container

Comment: Although this is a 2005 article, it might still be applicable today - Beware of transactions. http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2005/01/31/SSIS_3A00_-Beware-of-transactions.aspx

Comment: I found another link which is very helpful http://sqlblogging.com/2011/10/17/transactions-in-ssis-with-example/