# Can we use rollback(transactions) in Azure blob while uploading multiple files using SSIS package?

Tags: ssis, transactions, azure-blob-storage, rollback

I am using ssis to upload multiple files to azure blob storage. Requirement is when any of the file upload fail we need to rollback transactions. I have tried the transaction option in ssis but so far i am not able to rollback data from blob storage.

Has anyone tried the rollback option in azure blob storage? Please do let me know your thoughts on this.

Thanks
Vidya

Comment: You can use Sequence Container for the same. please refer to this thread : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/0e393e8f-8a60-4c28-abbf-177c0ebd26f3/how-i-can-perform-transaction-rollback-in-ssis-?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Also, you can refer this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/sequence-container?view=sql-server-2017

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options. If you are importing .csv or AVRO files, you can use the [SQL Server Integration Services Feature Pack for Azure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt146770.aspx) installed where:

> The [Azure Blob Source component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/azure-blob-source?view=sql-server-2017) enables an SSIS package to read data from an Azure blob. The supported file formats are: CSV and AVRO.

If you are not working with these file formats, then the solution offered in this SO thread: [How to transaction rollback in ssis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626755/how-to-transaction-rollback-in-ssis) with the use of Sequence Containers.

The SSIS Feature Pack for Azure contains connectors for various other data services and might be useful if you are going to be consuming additional services in the future.